NAudio - Start mp3 while other mp3 still running
Let's assume we have an endless list of mp3's. At a given point each mp3 fades out (different for each mp3), and the next mp3 starts. So for a short period of time there are the new mp3 and the fading out mp3 together. As it will be streamed away to an icecast server, this must happen inside a buffer.
Right now in a first try I just take two songs from my disk, but the plan is to load songs from everywhere.
I am so stuck, may be someone can help. Tnx in advance!
static byte[] buff = new byte[64];
static int read;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  icecast.Open();

  // to make things easier, first just take two songs out of a List
  Song actualSong = songs2play[0];
  Song nextSong = songs2play[1];

  BinaryReader actualSongReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(actualSong.Path, FileMode.Open));
  BinaryReader nextSongReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(nextSong.Path, FileMode.Open));
  
  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  while (true)
  {
     TimeSpan howLong = DateTime.Now - start;

     // if the next song starts
     if (howLong.Milliseconds > (actualSong.Length - actualSong.FadeoutStart) && (howLong.Milliseconds < (actualSong.Length - actualSong.FadeoutStart + actualSong.FadeoutLength)))
     {
         read = (actualSongReader.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) + nextSongReader.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
     }

     // the first song faded away, play only the new song
     else if (howLong.Milliseconds > (actualSong.Length))
     {
         read = nextSongReader.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
     }

     // only the first song, thew fade out point was not reached yet
     else
     {
         read = actualSongReader.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
     }

     // send buffer to icecast 
     if (read > 0)
     {
         icecast.Send(buff, read);
     }
     else 
       break;
 }


    public class Song
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Artist;
        public int Length;
        public int FadeoutStart;
        public int FadeoutLength;
        public string Path;
    }


You will need to mix the 2 audio signals. From NAudio documentation, this is feasible : https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/MixTwoAudioFilesToWav.md (and then recompress to MP3 to send to icecast)
